# How to enlarge the font in Zoom's chat?

Tags: zoom-meeting, macos-bigsur

I would like to know how I can increase the font size in the chat of the video conferencing program Zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the font size of the text in Zoom using the hot-keys `Ctrl +` to increase the size, and `Ctrl -` to decrease the size, when Zoom is your active window. This will increase or decrease the size of all text elements, including the chat text. The setting is also saved for future Zoom meetings.

An alternative approach is to navigate to Zoom's settings and adjust it there. This can be found by going to `Zoom > Settings > Accessibility` on the main client window. An option is in this window called `Chat Display Size`. Per-OS instructions with screenshots can be found here: [Changing settings in the desktop client or mobile app](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362623-Changing-settings-in-the-desktop-client-or-mobile-app)

You can change the font size for closed captioning and chat.

> - Closed Captioning: Click and drag the slider to make closed captions smaller or larger.
> - Always show meeting controls: Make the meeting controls visible at all times. If disabled, meeting controls will hide if your mouse
>   pointer is inactive for a few seconds.
> - Chat Display Size: Adjust the font size for in-meeting and IM chats.
> - Screen Reader Alerts: Enable or disable screen reader alerts.

This setting will only affect your local Zoom client.

Comment: This does not work on my macOS system. Neither Ctrl-+, Command-+, Option-+. Seems as if this is missing in macOS.

Comment: It looks like an alternative approach here is to go to `Zoom > Settings > Accessibility`. In this window there should be an option to adjust the chat text size. https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362623-Changing-settings-in-the-desktop-client-or-mobile-app

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the shortcut Command-+ does not work though, seems to be a bug, Command-- works:

[image: Solved]